# get_template_directory_uri not dependent on WP_HOME in wp-config.php?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, site-url, home-url

For testing on mobile devices in my local network, I've set up xip.io according to [this blogpost](https://pixeline.be/blog/mobile-testing-wordpress-php-installation-running-mamp-via-xip-io-3972.html)

I can access the site, but even though I added the following to my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://projectname.192.168.1.102.xip.io/projectname');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://projectname.192.168.1.102.xip.io/projectname');
```

all URLs defined with

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'projectname', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/projectname.css' );
```

resolve to

> http://projectname/css...